# What does the poet Sukanta Bhattacharya mean when he said he has to make room for the newborn?

Tags: poetry, sukanta-bhattacharya, bengali-language

Why does the poet here want to clean up this squalid earth and make room for them when everybody in this world is running after wealth, glamour, glory, fame and egotistical nature's distortion?

Did his eyes meet the empty, blurry, bleak, and beady eyes of void people as contemporary poet T. S. Elliot called them Hollow Man and Stuffed Man who doesn't have the spinal chord to stand up on the justifying and rational ground during Sukanta's lifetime and the poet rebelled against them? Is that the reason why? And he is adamant about his desire to clean up this world. He says as long as I have the breath in my body I will do it... If you look at the last few lines the poet says:

> Have to go away- Still, today till there is life in  body
>
> Earnestly I’ll remove the garbage of this world,
>
> I’ll make this world livable for this child before I go –
>
> That is my surefooted promise to this newborn.
>
> Finally completing all works
>
> I will bless this new child
>
> By the blood from my body,
>
> After that, I’ll be history only.

Here is the full poem:

> CHHARPATRA (Approval Certificate)
>
> Sukanta Bhattacharya
>
> The child who has born tonight
>
> From him I came to know:
>
> He has got an approval certificate,
>
> That’s why he expresses his right at the door of world
>
> Through his vigorous cry at his birth.
>
> Small body, helpless, still his clenched fist
>
> Raised and floated
>
> In some incomprehensible pledge.
>
> Nobody can understand his speech
>
> Some laughs, some give him mild scold.
>
> But I have realized that language
>
> He has got a letter of new era—
>
> I read the identity of that baby,
>
> In illegible mystic eyes.
>
> Arrived a new life, we have to give space for him,
>
> (We) failure in weird world,death and debris on our back
>
> We have to go away.
>
> Have to go away- Still, today till there is life in  body
>
> Earnestly I’ll remove the garbage of this world,
>
> I’ll make this world livable for this child before I go –
>
> That is my surefooted promise to this newborn.
>
> Finally completing all works
>
> I will bless this new child
>
> By the blood from my body,
>
> After that, I’ll be history only.